# Need iptables rule to block web traffic from eth0

Tags: firewall

I have 2 ports on my ubuntu 14.04 box:  eth0 and wlan0

I want eth0 to only be used for clients to ssh into, and I want all web traffic to only go out of wlan0.  So, nothing out of eth0 destined for port 80 or 443

What is the correct syntax for an iptables rule to enforce that?

Answer (score 0):

To block dest ports `80,443` out of `eth0`, you need this `OUTPUT` rule:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DROP`

If the connection originates from a device other than the firewall (i.e. if you have client using firewall as router), then you'll need to also include a `FORWARD` rule to block that traffic as well. You can copy the above rule and replace `OUTPUT` with `FORWARD` to accomplish that.

BEGIN EDIT

Please note that depending on your routing table, outbound web connections to the Internet may still go out of `eth0`, in which case all outbound web connections will be dropped. AFAIK there is no `iptables` rule to overwrite routing table definitions.. perhaps somebody else could shed some light on this?

END EDIT

In regards to your "only ssh into eth0" rule, use the following:

`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp ! --dport 22 -j DROP`

This will drop any connection that is not `tcp/22` coming into `eth0`.

Hope this helps.